# Insufficient privilege when I try to Create Table

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to oracle, I work on Pl/Sql Develper, I can create table by pl/sql Developer IDE  but I can't do that in query like :

```
Create Table table_name as select * from Docs
```

it returns Insufficient privilege error

can anybody tell me the reason...thanks in advance

Comment: If you can create tables using `create table (...);` then the error means you don't have the privileges to select from the table `DOCS`

Comment: Please run the following queries and append their results to the question: `select * from  USER_TAB_PRIVS where table_name = 'DOCS'` and `select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS WHERE privilege like 'CREATE%'`

Comment: thanks @kordirko ...the first query returns no row and the second return Create View Privilege...it looks that I don't have create table privilege...but my question still why I can create by pl/sql Developer IDE

Comment: @karlo please also check roles granted to your user using: `SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS`. I guess that the role `resource`  is granted to your user, and pl/sql developer enables that role while creating the table, but the role is disabled in the interactive session - you must "enable" that role for the session using `SET ROLE role-name`.

Answer (score -3):

please use SYSTEM user when you are connecting your database it has full privilege.

Comment: You should not create objects in the `system` schema. Use it to grant the necessary privileges to another schema and create objects under that.

Comment: I don't have the system user password

Comment: my question why I can do that by pl/sql Developer?

Comment: -1 that is a really bad advice. The `system` user should ***never*** be used to create regular tables. It is only intended for DBA activities (creating tablespaces, creating users).

Comment: SYSTEM user may not be available for a developer.

Comment: i know that but you can use SYSTEM user to create some tables also users or any object as a DBA for educational purpose not real world.